# Windows Batch Script: Grab the value under a particular column from a text file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a text file with multiple columns

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 AS_OF_DATE
1        2       3      07/12/2017
2        3       4      07/12/2017
.....
```

n number of rows
AS_OF_DATE represents the date of the data in the text file.It is same for all the rows.The place of AS_OF_DATE column can be at any place.
Now my requirement is to pick the date under the column AS_OF_DATE and store it in a separate file.

Any help in this appreciated.

Thanks
KVB

Comment: All the dates under the AS_OF_DATE column are same. It would help reading only first 1 or 2 lines to pull the value and assign it to a variable.Because i need to compare the AS_OF_DATE value with the current date and return exit 0 or 1 based on success/failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code makes many assumptions about your data:

- There are no `*` or `?` characters in your header line
- There are no poison characters like `&`, `|` etc. in your header line
- There are no spaces in your column names or column values
- All columns are fully populated
- Your input file uses standard Windows line endings or `<CR><LF>`, not unix ending of `<LF>`

There may be other constraints that I am not remembering

```
@echo off
setlocal

:: Define files
set "input=test.txt"
set "output=out.txt"

:: Read first (column header) line
<"%input%" set /p "ln="

:: Figure out which column contains AS_OF_DATE
for /f "delims=:" %%N in (
  'cmd /c "(for %%C in (%ln%) do @echo %%C)|findstr /n AS_OF_DATE"'
) do set "col=%%N"

:: Write all AS_OF_DATE values to a new file
>"%output%" (
  for /f "skip=1 usebackq eol= tokens=%col%" %%A in ("%input%") do echo %%A
)
```

**UPDATE:** ***Here is a modification that reads only the first 2 lines***

```
@echo off
setlocal

:: Define files
set "input=test.txt"
set "output=out.txt"

:: Read the first two lines
<"%input%" (
  set /p "header="
  set /p "data="
)

:: Figure out which column contains AS_OF_DATE
for /f "delims=:" %%N in (
  'cmd /c "(for %%C in (%header%) do @echo %%C)|findstr /n AS_OF_DATE"'
) do set "col=%%N"

:: Extract the AS_OF_DATE value and write to a new file
for /f "skip=1 eol= tokens=%col%" %%A in ("%data%") do >"%output%" echo %%A
```

Comment: Instead of pulling all the records in the file.Can we pull only first 2 records in the file and check this logic?

Comment: All the dates under the AS_OF_DATE column are same. It would help reading only first 1 or 2 lines to pull the value and assign it to a variable.Because i need to compare the AS_OF_DATE value with the current date and return exit 0 or 1 based on success/failure.

Comment: @oraclebharadwaj - I've updated my answer to read only first 2 lines.

Comment: i am facing issue with the script. The header variable is perfect but the data variable. It is picking up the data from the middle of the line and leading data is truncated.

Comment: it is starting from middle of 6th column.My data for 6th columns is 2018-02-25 00:00:00.0.For the first line it is picking from  "The value of data  is "2-25 00:00:00.0

Comment: even if i just give header to find the position of the column. It is displaying properly when echoed header variable.when used in for loop it is picking the header along with some data like next 2-3 lines. Unable to track the issue.

Comment: How to write header to a output file. I am trying to do that but ending up in printing ECHO is ON.

Comment: @oraclebharadwaj It's always difficult if OP isn't supplying necessary information. You should edit your question to include a more real life sample of your data. dbenham stated a lot of assumptions you didn't respond to. Looks like the 3rd one isn't true.